# Node Webpack Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux

I am trying to make an isomorphic react app with redux and webpack. But I seem to be hitting this error. The code actually points to a `firebase-node.js` file. I am not sure why I am getting this though. Is it related to my webpack config?

http://pastebin.com/DJVbJK43

Also here is my `server.js` where I am trying to do server-side rendering:

http://pastebin.com/kfHSEHBB

I get this error in Chrome console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:55185(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:55241(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:58721t @ bundle.js:formatted:10(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:14009t @ bundle.js:formatted:10(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:40521t @ bundle.js:formatted:10(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:40491t @ bundle.js:formatted:10(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:8852t @ bundle.js:formatted:10(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:44717t @ bundle.js:formatted:10(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:44689t @ bundle.js:formatted:10(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:44906t @ bundle.js:formatted:10(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:43284t @ bundle.js:formatted:10(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:29t @ bundle.js:formatted:10(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:18(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:formatted:19
```

THe formatted piece of code

```
var Dc = new Qc;
        !function() {
            var e = process.version;
            if ("v0.10.22" === e || "v0.10.23" === e || "v0.10.24" === e) {
                var t = function(e, t, n) {
                    this.chunk = e,
```

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: @ElodSzopos In chrome console

Comment: show me the console error

Comment: @RuiCosta updated question description

Comment: You are referencing `process` multiple times in your config. Which line is explicitly failing; the error should contain this.

Comment: @lux its failing in bundle.js in some firebase file. Not in my config.

Comment: Regardless of where the error is occurring, try to include that in your description. You need to display what code you are calling that's failing, otherwise what are you expecting people to deduce?

Comment: Have you got any control on `firebase-node.js`? You're talking about it like it's got nothing to do with you/your app...

Comment: @Ursus I am importing and using the library. But not modifying it. Also all seems to work fine when running in webpack dev without bundling.